# Problem with Unity APK Build : Default Activity (Android)

Tags: unity, android, build-process

There was a project developed in Unity 4.5. I successfully updated it to Unity 2018.2.3f1 version without any error. Runs perfectly in Editor. 
When I create an APK (internal). I just get this screen when I open it on a mobile.

[image: Screenshot, the default scene is not like this and is a splash scene]

But when I make a Windows/Mac Build, it runs perfectly. 
I've also tried on another Editor (version 2017.3.x) and APK built from this is also good. 
I've re-installed Unity, nothing... Also updated the SDK but still a problem.

Some other projects' APK is built successfully with the scenes and everything but they also have some strange problems. 
Note: I cannot shift back to 2017.3.x. 
Is it a problem the latest Editor? OR Is it a problem with my machine? 
What possibly could that be?

Comment: I have the same problem, and i know where it's comming from but i can't fix it. The problem occurs when i try to log in google play services and the result is just the same as yours or the game crashes. I'm also using Unity 2018.2.3f1 and i guess it's not compatible with google play services.

Comment: Alright... In my case, I don't have Play Services. But some other plugins.. Maybe its because of that..
But no solution.. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it , I downgraded unity to 2018
1.2f1 I think, built it again and when I ran it everything was working fine :) Good luck with fixing the error, I hope that I helped at least a bit

Comment: I'll try with 2018 1.2f1.. Because I really need to work 2018.. Although it was working fine on 2017.